# How do I get a reference to an event stream from a within an event handler?

Tags: dart, dart-webui, web-component

I have a need to manage a global state of a number of web components on my web page. (e.g. Each web component has a "select" button/function and I track components to make sure only one component is selected at a time.)

To manage the global state of my components, each web component provides a stream of events to a common handler in my main web app. Unfortunately, I need my handler to know which stream/web-component it was called from in order to manage the global state. How can my handler get this information?

Here is my sample code:

```dart
// _webComponents is a list of references to each component. 
// getStream() gets a stream of events from each component.
// connections is a list of streams from all my web components.
_webComponents.forEach((connection)=>connections.add(connection.getStream()));  
connections.forEach((Stream<String> connection)=>connection.listen(eventHandler));


void eventHandler(webComponentEvent){
    // ?? How do i find out which web component the event came from ?? 
    // ToDo: use event and web component info to manage a global state of web components.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to know the sender in your handler, right?

There are two options. The first one is to send the sender as a part of data:

```java
class Dog { // controller and stream initialization removed for brevity
  Stream get onBark => ...;
  void bark(){
    // of course, you can have a typed object instead of map
    _barkController.add({'sender': this, 'data': 'woof'});
  }
}

// attach to source
var dog = new Dog();
dog.onBark.listen((event) {
   sender = event['sender'];
   data = event['data'];
   ...
});
```

Another option is to bind the sender in the closure. This doesn't require you to change the type of stream (so you will still have `Stream<String>` instead of `Stream<Map>`:

```java
sources.forEach((src) => src.listen((data) => handleEvent(src, data)));

void handleEvent(Connection sender, String data) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I like the second option.  It worked liked a charm.